How do I send an email only to the most recent submission on a google form?
I am trying to automate a process for work. Essentially, I have a google form that people can use to check in that once submitted, will send them an email with their table assignment for an event. However, the problem that I have been running into is that it emails ALL of the prior submissions again after a new submission. I have automated the spreadsheet to pull the information from the form submission, assign the correct table number, and then put the information in a different tab called 'Check In'. The trigger "yes" essentially checks to see if they have checked in yet.
This code does exactly what I want it to, except that it sends emails to ALL submissions when there is a new submission. I only want the email to be sent to the most recent submission, which will be at the bottom of the list generated from submissions.
**function sendAutomaticEmail() {
function sendAutomaticEmail() {
var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
var data = dataRange.getValues();

for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {

var emailAddress = data[i][1]; 
var condition = data[i][3]; 
var name = data [i][2]
var seating = data [i][4]

if (condition === "Yes") {

var subject = 'Thank you for checking in! ';

var message = "Dear " + name +  ", thank you for checking in. You will be seated at table      number " + seating + "." ;

MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

}

}

}

**
How do I fix the code so that the email is only sent to the last row on the 'Check In' tab when there is a new submission (and not to everyone above that!)?
The code above does exactly what I want it to, other than the fact that it sends emails to everyone on the google spreadsheet that I have been working with. I think it has something to do with the "for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {" line (beginner in GAS, don't know for sure).

Would replacing that for-loop with var i = data.length - 1; be sufficient to choose the right row? (You would also need to delete one of the closing brackets)
